# Django HTML Dropdown with multiple values filter

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, django

I have this below mentioned dropdown with multiple values for each option

```html
<div class="form-wrapper">
    <label>Fruits Selected</label>
    <input type="text" readonly class="form-control" id="fruits_selected" name="fruits_selected" value="{{fruits_selected.product}}" />
</div>
<div class="form-row last">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
        <label for="">Fruits Type</label>
        <select id="Fruits" name="Fruits" class="form-control">
            <option disabled="disabled" selected="selected">Choose option</option>
            <option value="Mango,Apple,Orange"> Fresh Fruits</option>
            <option value="Onion,Tomato"> Vegetable</option>
            <option value="Apple,Beetroot,Carrot"> Diet Fruits</option>
            <option value="Apple,Grapes"> Healthy Fruits</option>
            <option value="Tomato,Mango"> Juice Items</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Via Django, I will get the fruits like Apple, Orange.
If the input in the `{{fruits_selected.product}}` is **Apple** then in the dropdown, I need to get the options `Fresh Fruits, Diet Fruits, Healthy Fruits` since the dropdown value consist **Apple**

Similarly, if the option in `{{fruits_selected.product}}` is **Tomato** then in the dropdown, I need to get the options `Vegetable, Juice Items` since the dropdown value consist **Tomato**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in template, although in view it is better to do:

if you have a multiselect:

```
{% with product=fruits_selected.product %} <-- Tomato? Fruits? -->
    <select id="Fruits" name="Fruits" class="form-control">
        <option disabled="disabled" {% if not prodict %}selected{% endif %}>Choose option</option>
        <option {% if product in "Mango,Apple,Orange" %}selected{% endif %} value="Mango,Apple,Orange"> Fresh Fruits</option>
        <option {% if prodict in "Onion,Tomato" %}selected{% endif %} value="Onion,Tomato"> Vegetable</option>
        <option {% if prodict in "Apple,Beetroot,Carrot" %}selected{% endif %} value="Apple,Beetroot,Carrot"> Diet Fruits</option>
        <option {% if prodict in "Apple,Grapes" %}selected{% endif %} value="Apple,Grapes"> Healthy Fruits</option>
        <option {% if product in "Tomato,Mango" %}selected{% endif %} value="Tomato,Mango"> Juice Items</option>
    </select>
{% endwith %}
```

if you want to remove options:

```
{% with product=fruits_selected.product %} <-- Tomato? Fruits? -->
    <select id="Fruits" name="Fruits" class="form-control">
        <option disabled selected>Choose option</option>
        {% if product in "Mango,Apple,Orange" %}<option value="Mango,Apple,Orange"> Fresh Fruits</option>{% endif %} 
        {% if prodict in "Onion,Tomato" %}<option value="Onion,Tomato"> Vegetable</option>{% endif %} 
        {% if prodict in "Apple,Beetroot,Carrot" %}<option value="Apple,Beetroot,Carrot"> Diet Fruits</option>{% endif %} 
        {% if prodict in "Apple,Grapes" %}<option value="Apple,Grapes"> Healthy Fruits</option>{% endif %} 
        {% if product in "Tomato,Mango" %}<option value="Tomato,Mango"> Juice Items</option>{% endif %} 
    </select>
{% endwith %}
```

Comment: considering product is Apple, the last one would be selected at the end!

Comment: Sorry, I selected Apple like `product='Apple' `, This is not working as expected :( I am getting all the options.

Comment: @Moses01 - i am not sure, what you want, but i update the answer.